# How to get Query parameter with JS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, parameters

Can I put in some variable some Parameter from Query String Parameters?

i.e.

**Headers:**

General....

Response Headers....

Request Headers....

Query String Parameters: name:john home:london

```
/page.php?name=john&home=london
```

I need var nameQuery = john or var homeQuery = london

Answer (score 5):

There is a much better way to get query params than parsing a string.

Now, an official API called [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is available, very easy to use.

```js
var queryString = "?id=1234&action=edit"
var queryParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
// p.s. you can get the query string by plain JS like
// var queryString = window.location.search;

console.log(queryParams.has('id')); // true
console.log(queryParams.get('action')); // "edit"
console.log(queryParams.getAll('action')); // ["edit"]
console.log(queryParams.toString()); // "?id=1234&action=edit"
queryParams.append('ref', 'top_page')
console.log(queryParams.toString()); // "?id=1234&action=edit&ref=top_page"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use split() for this liek bellow,

```js
 var url = window.location.href;
 var params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'); 
 for(var i =0;i<params.length;i++){
  var temp = params[i].split('=');
  var key   = temp[0];
  var value = temp[1];
  console.log(key +':'+value);
 }
```

**Result**

```
   name:john
   home:london
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var url = '/page.php?name=john&home=london';
var params = url.split('?')[1].split('&');//get the url params array seperated from url 
var queryObj = {};
for(i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
  pair = params[i].split('='); //spilt to key and value
  queryObj[ pair[0] + 'Query' ] = pair[1];
}
console.log(queryObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.search`, which will give you:

```
"?name=john&home=london"
```

So, using the above info, you can separate them this way:

```
search = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
```

Which you will get:

```
["name=john", "home=london"]
```

That you can loop and get the values.

```
var stuff = {};
for (i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
  thing = search[i].split("=");
  stuff[thing[0]] = thing[1];
}
```

And finally, logging `stuff` you get:

```
Object {name: "john", home: "london"}
```

You can use:

```
stuff.name; // john
stuff.home; // london
```